# How to get the Flurry Data for Custom reporting

Tags: android, analytics, flurry

i want to get the Flurry Data for My Application for Custom report in my Website for my Application
is there any way to do it ?

Thanks in Advance
Sangeeth

Comment: http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart/Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flurry has a number of APIs to allow you to export your data. Based on standard formats such as XML and JSON, these APIs can be integrated into web dashboards, data warehouses and any other system you might use for managing your business. More information on this is available here: http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=API
(Full Disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: 'event log' is not avaialble through your API, please check at your request board case 40055